# rails heroku - how to install javascript dependences that needs 'npm install ...'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, heroku, npm

I am deploying my rails app to heroku. I want to use some javascript libraries which want us to install npm dependencies like this:

```
npm install abc
```

So, locally I can do like installing npm and doing 'npm install abc'. Not sure how to do it in heroku along with my rails app.

Answer (score 12):

Use the multiple builds approach from Heroku:

[Using Multiple Buildpacks for an App](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app)

By having the NodeJS one first and then the Ruby one, Heroku will install your node dependencies before anything happens in Ruby.

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
```

That will set the build pack to `heroku/ruby` and then add the `heroku/nodejs` one but in index 1 (which is first). To confirm this, run:

```
heroku buildpacks
=== ... Buildpack
1. heroku/nodejs
2. heroku/ruby
```

Comment: I used https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi and it was pretty easy to figure out how to handle my usecase

Comment: heroku-buildpack-multi is deprecated and will cease to function in 2017

Comment: @philpirozhkov that is good to know -- looks like deprecated in favor of Heroku's built-in multi support: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app

Comment: @Cymen please update your answer accordingly. There's no `.buildpack` file anymore.

Comment: @philpirozhkov Ah, I didn't realize it changed that much. I edited.

Comment: So how can you install specific npm packages in production after you have set both buildpacks?

Comment: @Michael If I recall correctly (not using Heroku much anymore), the `heroku/nodejs` will detect package.json file and run `npm install` (and probably do some other things).

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying a Node app, declare it in your package.json, otherwise, specific it in your gemfile.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#declare-dependencies-with-npm

Comment: +1   It is not Node app, it is rails app. But need a js library. for installing that, we need to do things like 'npm install ..', so I think I need to specify in gemfile. And, how to specify in gemfle? For npm, i can do `gem npm`. what about 'npm install abc'. Where shud I specify this 'abc' in gemfile and how. I thnk I cant do like `gem abc` as it will search in rails gems for the gem 'abc' but it is found using npm